# Same values , Same Class but Comparison of both gives FALSE result

Tags: r, linear-regression

I used the following data and tried to compare the Residuals values provided by the model and calculated manually. Both results are same by visual inspection but R is behaving in a different manner.

```
library(MASS)
lm.fit=lm(medv~lstat,data=Boston)

Boston$lmedv[1:10]             #Actual values 
[1]  24.0 21.6 34.7 33.4 36.2 28.7 22.9 27.1 16.5 18.9

lm.fit$fitted.values[1:10]     #Predicted values 
 1         2          3         4         5         6         7            
29.822595 25.870390 30.725142 31.760696 29.490078 29.604084 22.744727 

 8            9        10 
16.360396  6.118864 18.307997

a<-Boston$medv[1:10]-lm.fit$fitted.values[1:10]  #Manual Cal. of Residual
  1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
-5.8225951 -4.2703898  3.9748580  1.6393042  6.7099222 -0.9040837  0.1552726 

   8          9         10 
10.7396042 10.3811363  0.5920031 

lm.fit$residuals[1:10]                 #Residual cal. Provided by lm model
     1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
-5.8225951 -4.2703898  3.9748580  1.6393042  6.7099222 -0.9040837  0.1552726 

     8          9         10 
10.7396042 10.3811363  0.5920031 

class(a)
[1] "numeric"

class(lm.fit$residual[1:10])
[1] "numeric"

a==lm.fit$residuals[1:10]
  1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 

table(a==lm.fit$residuals[1:10]
 FALSE  TRUE 
  6     4
```

The values are same and also their class is also same . But why R is behaving in a strange manner and listed them as FALSE in the comparison. Did i miss something ? Please tell me .

Comment: @roland please provide the link where it was asked . Thanks

Comment: Look at the top of your question.